# Add A and B to array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I add "A" and "B" to the arrays when they allready are created?

Allready this:

```
$array1 = array("green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("green", "yellow", "red");
```

Want this output

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: There are plenty of guides and tutorials on how to use arrays, this isn't a advanced or complex issue, do your own research

Comment: How would you add the A to the first array?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit after comment*

```
$array1 = array("red","green","blue");
array_unshift($array1, "A");
```

Comment: No I want to ad "A" to the first array, like the headline of the array. Note the =>

Comment: Edited, Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: Almost how can I make it look like: array("A" => "red","green","blue"); With SUM and bigger than.